# The scrollbar jumps when dynamic height content in LazyVStack inside ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(replys) {
                    Text($0.content)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The content of reply is variable, so the height of Text is dynamic. When scrolling, the scrollbar is jumping. Here is the [original question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685461)

Comment: I can confirm, happens with me too. But only the scroll bar indicator jumps, the scrolling is smooth. And this seems logical, because LazyVStack is loading new items lazily, so it only knows by loading time what size they have, and then updates the scroll indicator. I suppose there is nothing you can do about that – except skip the Lazy and use a regular VStack ...

Comment: @ChrisR How UIKit solve this problem? By the way, I am not familiar with UIKit totally